# Cell function for determining another cell value in the same row returned by max function (excel)

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I don't really know how to ask this via google, so I'll just do a description here.

I am using excel, and I have a table like so

```
Pushups

A          B    C
6/16/2016  45   35
6/17/2016  47   37
etc...
```

Basic pushups per day document. I know how to get my "best" day...

```
=max(B2:...)
=max(C2:...)
```

How do I programatically get the date for the best day? Essentially, I need to be able to take the index of the row that Max has selected, and then get the value from another column... column A. So, whatever the max is, I need a formula to get the value from column A in the same row.

Should be an easy one I think, just don't know enough excel.

Comment: duplicates are fine.. can I have it just take the first instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 =INDEX(A1:A4,MATCH(MAX(B1:B4),B1:B4,0))
```

OR

```
=INDEX(A1:A4;MATCH(MAX(B1:B4);B1:B4;0))
```

depending on Excel version and localization

Comment: This comes close to working. However, it represents 7/15/2016 as 42556. When I enclosed the date in quotes, it showed up as the correct thing "7/15/2016". How do I force excel to interpret the column as a date string and not some sequence of numbers to divide?

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below (modify **Column B** to whatever Column you are looking for the Maximum Value)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Date_of_Max()

Dim Row_Max         As Long
Dim Rng             As Range    

' modify your range here to whatever Column you want    
Set Rng = Range("B1:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
Row_Max = WorksheetFunction.Index(Rng, WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.Max(Rng), Rng, 0)).Row
MsgBox Range("A" & Row_Max)

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, this is in excel. I was looking for something I could drop inside a cell? Forgive me if I sound like an idiot.

Comment: Something like "=MAX(...)"

Comment: @Zack This is the equivalent formula: `=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A",INDEX(B:B,MATCH(MAX(B:B),B:B,0))))`

Comment: @Zack so please edit your original post, mention you are looking for a Cell Formula, and not VBA solution

Comment: Sorry Shai, will do